# Finding max and min nodes possible in a tree of depth k and with a branching factor of n

Tags: data-structures, tree, computer-science, abstract-data-type

I have a tree of depth k and branching factor of n. I've been trying to find a general formula for:

1. Maximum number of nodes possible in this tree
2. Minimum number of nodes possible in this tree

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but this is a trivially simple question for a data-structures course. I don't want to be rude or mean or anything of the sort, but this is about as simple as these questions get.

But you asked for suggestions, not solutions. This is a good thing. :-)

I would start with making sure you know the definition of branching factor. Then I would draw a pick a couple easy values for k,n like (1,1) (2,2) (3,2) and see what the result is. I promise you a pattern will emerge!

Edit:

So you have a grasp of the branching factor. Let's look at the minumum.

If you have a depth of k, you know that you can traverse along k different nodes right? So if none of those nodes have any other children, and the end node has no children, what can you say about the nodes there?

Okay that was easy. The maximum is a bit harder, but still fairly straightforward. The easiest way to look at it is to think less like a tree. Trees have a top and go down. Instead, think of this as a series of concentric circles, each circle representing a level of depth.

Let's start with (depth = 1). You know you're going to have just one node, right? I mean it can't have any children, because you're limited to 1 depth! Now, let's look at depth of 2. The starting node can have n (assuming n is the branching factor) child nodes. So that would be n + 1.

Now if we add one more to that, we end up with n nodes on the "outside ring" each of which can have n children. So you end up with n*n + n + 1.

On each successive ring, you end up with (nodes added last time) * (branching factor) + all existing nodes. Now can you think of a way to express that as a formula?

Comment: of course I drew the simple cases and tried to find a pattern but couldn't. Maybe my understanding of branching factor is wrong. And please spend the next few of your words for helping not for stating how easy it is.

Comment: Well, what do you think a branching factor is? What is your understanding of it?

Comment: If branching factor is k, it means every parent has at most k children?

Comment: @Dave right. So I added some more to my post about how I would go about solving it. The "hard" part is still there, but I think it's more manageable now. Learning to visualize your problems properly is the easiest way to solve them!

Comment: I thought that depth starts from 0. So, 0 depth should be the one with no children. I saw the same thing from many resources. The one you are mentioning is height. Isn't this the case? Are you confusing height with depth?

Comment: @Dave I wasn't confusing the two, although I was starting at 1 instead of 0. You are correct that (depth = 0) will have just the root node. Height and depth are essentially the same thing, except that one goes to the root and one goes from the root.

Comment: I agree with leo's response below for the maximum. That is the same formula I came with for max: sum(i=0 to n) k^i = (k^(n+1)-1)/(k-1)

And for min, I'd like to say that it is just k+n. But I'm not sure. Can you comment on that?

Comment: for max, I'd have to check the math. I would simply have expressed it as a sum. :) For the min, remember that you have a MAX of n, but a MIN of 0, unless it's on the critical path that enforces the depth of the tree, where you need at least 1 child. In other words, because N gives you an upper bound, you'd expect the minimum nodes of depth k, factor n (k,n) to be the same as (k,n+1). So with that in mind, how would it change your thoughts on the minimum?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the max number of nodes assume every new level is full.
In the first level you have 1 node, in the second n nodes, in the third you have n^2 nodes (n for each of the previous n), in the fourth you have n^3 (n for each of the previous n^2)...

This gives you sum(i=1, k-1, n^i) + 1 ==> (n(n^k -1))/(n-1) + 1

The min number of nodes is of course 0 :)

Comment: I agree with your max. But your min does not make sense.

Comment: And you don't need that +1. Just start the sum from i=0.

Comment: Well, the minimum number of nodes is the empty tree, isn't it?

Comment: Empty tree does not have a depth. It should have a depth, and the formula should be general including all cases. I'm leaning towards k+n right now (branching factor + depth) for the minimum, this is the result I got when I drew for few cases.

Comment: Well, in this case you have "depth" as the minimum number of nodes (assuming that your tree became a list).